# Cordova Android build versionCode with Gradle

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, android-manifest

I have an existing Cordova app that I am updating. The Cordova versions are: **Cordova 6.3.0** and **cordova-android 5.2.2** Google Play has started saying:

> "Upload failed. Your APK's version code needs to be higher than
>   2016032518"

(2016032518 is the currently released version).

My config.xml contains this:

`<widget android-versionCode="201608291" ios-CFBundleVersion="201608291" version="1.5.0"`

I am building with `cordova build android --release`

The AndroidManifest (in platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml) contains the correct versionCode:

`<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="201608291" android:versionName="1.5.0"`

I have tried:

1. Adding `versionCode 201608291` inside the `defaultConfig {}` block in *build.gradle*
2. Specifying the versionCode in the the build command like `cordova build android --release --versionCode=201608291`

Given that the file `platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml` contains the correct versionCode it seems that the built APK file does NOT have the right version.

How can I solve this?

How can I even see what version the compiled APK has?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the numbers:

```
android:versionCode="201608291"
```

`201608291` has 1 digit less than `2016032518`

VersionCodes are comparesd as integer values, so `201608291` is really lower than `2016032518`

Comment: Ah... I accidentally added a digit to that build in the previous release. Always look for the obvious! (thanks)